# Open file on macvim from Iterm2

Tags: macvim, iterm2

I always use `Command + click` to open file from iterm2.
However, it always open a new window instead a new tab of the existing windows.
What configuration do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the configuration need to be done in macvim.

1) Click on macvim > Preferences

2) Go to the General tab

3) In `Open files from applications:`, choose `in the current window`

Comment: Any other solution? This is not working for me now =(